# How to show the large image when click on image in wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

In a page i am displaying image,desc,etc fileds.whenever click on that small image need to display large size image and close icon also and need to show the blur of the background screen(for no user interaction in background fileds).whenever click on close icon need to show actual data.
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to have this on your page:

```
<Grid Name="datagrid">
    // your small image and other fields
</Grid>

<Grid Name="imagegrid" Visibility="Collapsed">
    // larger image and a button to "close"
</Grid>
```

On TAP event of the SMALL picture, change the datagrid visibility to collapsed and imagegrid visibility to visible.
On click event of the close button in imagegrid, change datagrid visibility to visible and imagegrid visibility to collapsed.

The second way to do this is to use another page with just a large picture and a close button. When the user taps on the small picture, navigate to that second page, and when the user taps close or back button, navigate back to the first page with small picture and all the fields.